# I cannot use Sweave to process a file created in TeXmaker (or Gedit) under Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, sweave, texmaker

I am attempting to use Sweave with R2.11.1 and Texmaker on Ubuntu 10.10. I have done this previously on Windows XP, where one saves the tex file as `.Rnw` and then processes it with Sweave. I have all the files in R's current working directory, but it does not appear to work.

Whenever I run the Sweave command, a blank tex file is created, and then R stops, giving me the following error:

```
 Error in SweaveReadFile(file, syntax) : 
     no Sweave file with name 'example.Snw' found
```

I even tried loading the example sweave file from the R tools library, and even that does not work. Can anyone advise if they know of a solution for this problem, or please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: I think we may need more information to figure this out.  How exactly do you run the Sweave command?  Are you running it from the shell, or from Texmaker?  What exact command line do you use? Is there something in your Rnw file that would try to include a file called "example.Snw'?  Could you create a minimal example of a Rnw file that causes this, and post it here?  What do you mean by "all the files"?

Comment: I opened up R in a terminal and set it to the directory which contains the Sweave file. The command Sweave(file.Rnw) produces the error noted above. I also tried .Snw and .rnw to assess if it was the extension which was the problem. The example file I was running can be found here: http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/example-1.Snw . I also tried running Sweave from the command line outside R, and got the same error.  I have now tracked down the source of the error - the Sweave command does not like names with spaces, even enclosed in quotes. Apologies for any time wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richie wrote in a comment above:

> I have now tracked down the source of the error - the Sweave command does not like names with spaces, even enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Answering so we can get this off the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: @Richie: It's only been there for less than a day!